# "AADSTS900144: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'grant_type'.?

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api

I built an app in my Azure ad b2c tenant and configured it as shown, but why can't I request an access token in postman?

[app registration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UYi9R.png)

[API permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JLhmw.png)

[postman screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2cLJU.png)

Here are the links to the two documents I follow：

[Register a Microsoft Graph application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/microsoft-graph-get-started?tabs=app-reg-ga)

[Get access without a user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service#4-get-an-access-token)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

One thing I noticed is that the parameters for the token request should be in the body as form parameters, like this:

[image: Parameters in Body tab of Postman with x-www-form-urlencoded selected]

You should use the parameters you've defined here though, this screenshot shows a test request for the ROPC flow so the parameters in the picture are not valid for your use case.

So instead of entering the parameters in Params, enter them in Body tab after selecting x-www-form-urlencoded as the type.

Answer (score 4):

Please input the params in "**Body**" tab of your postman but not "**Params**" tab. Shown as below screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In order to get token you need to pass grant_type in request body and value should be password.

For example

Method Post: https://login.microsoftonline.com/YourTenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

And in body you need to ppass
client_id : Your app client ID
scope: user.read%20openid%20profile%20offline_access
username: Your username
password: your password
grant_type: password
client_secret: you app registration secret

Answer (score 0):

I tried many times to put into body with JSON format or in parameter or put into Parameters, but I did not work. And it works for me when I put into Body with type is x-www-form-urlendcoded.
[Image]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tguZc.png

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).